# AngularJS: directive to toggle class depending on array value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm new to angular and I have a `ng-grid` table. I want to save the clicked elements in an array (so all elements uniquely correspond to table cells) and strike the cells through, that are in this array. This has to happen in "toggleable" way.

So far my cells look like:

`<div ng-click="myFunc(args)" ...><span>Text</span></div>`

and `myFunc` takes care of the array, which is in a factory. Now I did DOM manipulation from that same function but I thought to do it the angular way I should create a directive for the `span` element, which evaluates the array and depending on whether the object that corresponds to the cell containing that particular `span` will get a css class attached.

FYI: the elements in the array contain the coordinates of the cells as (x,y), they are stored for an interaction with the server.

Comment: Can you show an example of the `span` tag with and without the class added?

Comment: Bind your array to the scope and just use ng-class syntax to bind a class matching your condition.. go to angular doc

Comment: The condition was not that straightforward, but I wrote a function to evaluate that condition and it works fine with ng-class. Thanks!
There is one cleanness problem though. I have one property that supports the valuation of the condition, this property is defined in a factory. How can I refer to that property in the ng-class directive?

Comment: @DavinTryon Basically its just a span with or without a particular class. There is also one ng-grid related directive, but it doesnt matter, AFAIK at least.

Answer (score 0):

> Bind your array to the scope and just use ng-class syntax to bind a class matching your condition. The condition was not that straightforward, but I wrote a function to evaluate that condition and it works fine with ng-class